# File matches with structured information

Tags: bash, grep

The following `grep` command that returns the files that contain the string `ptrn`.  The `sed` command skips files using a step stored in `stp`.

```
grep -rl "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}" |
  sed "${sta}~${stp}!d" >> $logfl
```

This would be the result

```
cat /home/flora/logs/27043-T13:09:44.893003954.log
file1.sh
file2.sh
file3.sh
file4.sh
file5.sh
file6.sh
```

I would like to end up with the following

```
cat /home/flora/logs/27043-T13:09:44.893003954.log
File: file1.sh
+ file2.sh
+ file3.sh
+ file4.sh
+ file5.sh
+ file6.sh
```

I do not think one can do that with `grep` though.  Some will likely recommend using `awk` on the file `logfl`.

Comment: So all you want is add prefix `File:` in 1st line and `+` in all other lines?

Comment: What are the values of your variables?

Comment: Yes, that is shat I want to do @alecxs. Have put one solution.  Would you have a better one, if I may ask?

Comment: Oh you already found yourself what I had in mind :)

Comment: Fantastic. Respect buddy.  I got a further challenge.  Interested @alecxs?

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU rectools (which you mention [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678530/reading-from-structured-file-to-invoke-a-grep-on-matches#comment1281700_678530) to another of your questions):

```bsh
: >output

recins -f File -v "$(cat logfile)" output
```

This creates or empties the file called `output`, and then inserts a single field called `File` with a value that is the contents of the file `logfile`.

Note that the `+` counts as a newline character in the GNU recfile format, so what the above does is to insert *a single value*, containing embedded newline characters.

If you want to insert each filename as a separate element, you could use

```bsh
: >output

xargs -I {} recins -f File -v {} output <logfile
```

The above calls `recins` once per line in `logfile` and inserts a separate key-value pair for each.

This could be done more efficiently if we let the input be a CSV file:

```bsh
{ echo File; cat logfile; } | csv2rec >output
```

The `echo` command is used here to prepend the CSV header to the input data for `csv2rec`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem this way

```
 grep -rl "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}" |
    sed '1s/^/File: /;1!s/^/+ /' >> $logfl
```