# Reading from structured file to invoke a grep on matches

Tags: bash, grep

Have got a log file with a structured list of filenames with the first file being identified by the descriptor `File:`, with the remaining files being on a separate line with a `+` character at the beginning.

I want to have a loop that prints the file names using a matching pattern as soon as `File:` is detected.  Then it will continue picking up filenames with `+` at the start.  The file reading stops when one reaches an empty line, or another field name is encountered (e.g. `Package:` )

```
cat /home/flora/logs/27043-T13:09:44.893003954.log
%rec: dyna

Ptrn: Gnu
File: /home/flora/dynamic.sh
+ /home/flora/comint.sh
+ /home/flora/linge/engine.sh
+ /home/flora/Opstk/playa.sh
+ /home/flora/bin/edv.sh
+ /home/flora/Opstk/bin/ling.rc
+ /home/flora/parade.rc
System: 64-Bit
```

Have started with a simple `read` so as not to cause out of memory problems should one use a variable to store the whole list of files.

```
while IFS= read -rd '' fl; do
  grep --color -ni -C 8 -e "$ptrn" -- "$fl"
done < "$logfl"
```

`ptrn` defines the search pattern invoked on each file.

Comment: Are all of the log files in the same directory? Is there anything else in the directory?

Comment: I have responded to your question by updating the logfile contents.  The path is included with the file name.

Comment: What's the question please?

Comment: That I need to handle the removal of `File:` and `+` as I read through the lines.

Comment: Because there can be additional information preceeding the `File:` field, I cannot simply rely on matching a space.

Comment: Why are you asking us to strip the initial "File" and the plus symbols if your [earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/678446/100397) asked how to put them in? It would make far more sense to tell us what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I was making a standard rec file that can be processed by Gnu Recutils.  So I have the option to make and read recfiles by my scripts.  It is not to wind you up, I promise.

Comment: What's the question here? Your post says you have this read loop, but you're not saying anything about it failing, or actually asking anything at all? I'm not even sure what it is you're trying to do. Do you just want to pick the whole list of filenames? 
Or just the ones matching some pattern? Where does that pattern come from? Does the line `Ptrn: Gnu` have anything to do with it, or is it just given somewhere outside? You really should [edit] the question to show the expected output you'd like to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use process substitution and pass only lines with file names to loop (instead of whole file)

```
while IFS= read -r fl; do
  grep --color -ni -C 8 -e "$ptrn" -- "$fl"
done < <(grep -o '/.*' "$logfl")
```

or process whole file but skip line by line until keyword `File:` appears, then process line by line with string manipulation `/${fl#*/}` until keyword `+` disappears, then stop reading

```
# some control flags
begin=
exit=continue

while IFS= read -r fl; do
  case ${fl%[[:blank:]]*} in
    *File:*)
      begin=start
    ;;
    *+*)
      exit=break
    ;;
    *)
      $exit
    ;;
  esac
  [ "$begin" ] && \
  grep --color -ni -C 8 -e "$ptrn" -- "/${fl#*/}"
done < "$logfl"
```

Comment: Yes.  This is what I would like.

Comment: Would you explain what `"/${fl#*/}"` is about?

Comment: I do not think the condition `[ "$begin" ]` is really required though.

Comment: It is required to ensure `File:` was encountered then.  Right?

Comment: it is required to ignore path names above and below keywords `File:` and `+` (for example when `Ptrn:` and `System:` contains/is followed by path names (matches regexp/contains `/` slash). if you delete the `begin` condition the whole solution is obsolete and you can just use the first example instead. `${string#substring}` is substring removal (delete shortest substring `*/` from left `#`) https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: And you include the first `/` because `"${fl#*/}"` will remove the starting `/` in the path.

Answer (score 1):

[In comments to the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678530/reading-from-structured-file-to-invoke-a-grep-on-matches#comment1281700_678530), you mentioned that you had put this data into a format readable by the GNU `recutils` set of tools.

Let's use those tools to extract the pathnames and call `grep`:

```bsh
recsel -P File -- "$logfl" | xargs -I {} grep -e "$ptrn" -- {}
```

This selects and prints the values associated with the `File` field in the file named by `$logfl`.  For each line produced by the `recsel` command, `xargs` calls `grep` to pull out the lines matching the basic regular expression in `$ptrn`.

Note that what you have in the file in the question is a *single* value, containing embedded newline characters.

If you were to have a record file with multiple `File` fields with individual values, you would instead use

```bsh
recsel -C -P File -- "$logfl" | xargs -I {} grep -e "$ptrn" -- {}
```

Comment: Yes, one can use these tools like `recsel`.